# extract information in between the * symbol of the text and save each data into a separate array

Tags: php, arraylist, file-handling, preg-split, array-splice

I have a text file as "**`a.txt`**",

which has a data like the image. I want to read this text file line by line and save each entry between the **`*`** symbol and save into a separate `array`.

> Note: each information I want to save into a separate array.

I want to do this using PHP code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show your code , any try??

Comment: I do not have any idea how to achieve it. Please suggest...here is my output text file format.

Comment: * [(2R)-2-hydroxy-3-[2-(prop-2-en-1-yl)phenoxy]propyl](isopropyl)azanium * 250.181 *C15H24NO2 *2 *1 *46 *1 *11 *1.1266 *1 *18 *6 *18 *6 *4 * C[C@H](C)[NH2+]C[C@H](COc1ccccc1CC=C)O"/> Vendors*

Comment: have you tried explode??

Answer (score 0):

you can try explode for this . if it works

```
 $handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $array=array();
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // process the line read.
         $array[]=explode('*',$line);
        }

        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        // error opening the file.
    }
print_r($array);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => [(2R)-2-hydroxy-3-[2-(prop-2-en-1-yl)phenoxy]propyl](isopropyl)azanium   
            [2] => 250.1â€Œâ€‹81C15H24NO2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 46
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 11
            [8] => 1.1266
            [9] => 1
            [10] => 18
            [11] => 6
            [12] => 18
            [13] => 6
            [14] => 4
            [15] => C[C@H](C)[NH2+]C[C@Hâ€Œâ€‹](COc1ccccc1CC=C)O"/> Vendors 

        )

)
```

Comment: Hi Ris, Thank you for  your reply and code. Printing is not a problem. using explode, I am able to print separately. But, I want to store each data into a separate array so that I can insert into my database in a automated way.

Comment: you can add `$array` into db  with for loop or foreach  loop . what's the problem??/

Comment: Actually, I am scraping some database and trying to pull large data using file get contents from html page and removing unwanted fields from there and able to print in webpage as well as a text file successfully but my issue is to read the text file line by line and find the matches and insert into database. Here is my code for whole--

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen("curl.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "somehtml page");                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$lines = file("curl.txt");
foreach ($lines as $line){
 if (preg_match("!<td>(.*?)</td>!si", $line)){
 $string = str_replace(array("\r"), '', $line);
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/Name/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '*';
$txt = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
$results = print_r($txt, true); 
file_put_contents('a.txt', print_r($results, true), FILE_APPEND); }}

Answer (score 0):

My code

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen("curl.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "htmlpage");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$lines = file("curl.txt");

/* Priint data of Supernatural Database in between the html tags */
foreach ($lines as $line){
 if (preg_match("!<td>(.*?)</td>!si", $line)){

/* string match and replace in html tags */

$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $line);
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/Name/';
$patterns[1] = '/Molecular weight/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '*';
$replacements[1] = '*';


$txt = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);

$results = print_r($txt, true); 
file_put_contents('a.txt', print_r($results, true), FILE_APPEND);

/* remove all the html tags from output */
echo strip_tags($results, '<p><a><br>');
$strip_txt = strip_tags($results, '<p><a><br>');


 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- (2R)-2-hydroxy-3-[2-(prop-2-en-1-yl)phenoxy]propylazanium  *   250.181 *C15H24NO2  *2  *1  *46 *1  *11 *1.1266 *1  *18 *6  *18 *6  *4  *   CC@H[NH2+]CC@HO"/> Vendors* Ambinter Supplier code: Ambmdy02300166   *   (1S,17R,18R,19R)-17,18-dihydroxy-5,7-dioxa-12-azapentacyclo[10.6.1.0Â²,Â¹â°.0â´,â¸.0Â¹âµ,Â¹â¹]nonadeca-2,4(8),9,15-tetraen-12-ium  *   288.124 *C16H18NO4  *3  *2  *63 *1  *2  *0.9007 *5  *